# How to add language support on CentOS 7 (on Docker)?

Tags: centos, yum, docker

I'm trying to set locale to Japanese, but CentOS image on docker doesn't include language support.

```
bash-4.2# yum groupinstall -y "Japanese Support"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.btte.net
 * extras: centos.mirror.secureax.com
 * updates: centos.mirror.secureax.com
Warning: group Japanese Support does not exist.
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

I've checked grouplist by `yum grouplist` and `yum grouplist hidden` and neither include Japanese Support.
Is there any way to install Japanese Support?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem with a RHEL 7.4 docker image. `yum reinstall glibc-common` by itself didn't resolve the problem. It was only installing English.

I found in my docker container `/etc/yum.conf` contained the line `override_install_langs=en_US`. This caused `yum reinstall glibc-common` to only install English.

With this line commented out (or changed to the default value of all), and re-running `yum reinstall glibc-common` I was able to use other languages

Initial Environment after docker run/attach

```
# locale -a
C
POSIX
en_US.utf8
# grep lang /etc/yum.conf
override_install_langs=en_US
# export LANG=fr_FR
# ls foo
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
```

My attempt at reinstalling glib-common before changing `/etc/yum.conf`

```
# yum -y -q reinstall glibc-common
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
# ls foo
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
# locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
POSIX
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
#
```

After changing `/etc/yum.conf` to comment out the line `override_install_langs=en_US`

```
# vi /etc/yum.conf
# grep lang /etc/yum.conf
#override_install_langs=en_US
# yum -y -q reinstall glibc-common
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
# ls foo
ls: cannot access foo: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
# locale -a | wc -l
789
```

Comment: On the `centos:7.9.2009` docker image, it was enough to run `yum-config-manager --setopt override_install_langs= --save` before running `yum upgrade` to solve this. Thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

[You need to reinstall the `glibc-common` package.](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/issues/10) Here is the proof:

```
docker run -it --rm centos bash -c 'locale -a | wc -l && yum -y -q reinstall glibc-common && locale -a | wc -l'
53
789
```

Note: `locale -a` lists installed locales, and `wc -l` counts them, so those numbers are the number of locales before and after reinstalling `glibc-common`.